# How to convert string to double in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, type-conversion

I have a script in PowerShell that I am using to import data from a CSV. I am receiving an error

---

Cannot convert value "Journal Amount" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\TestPowerShell\TestPowerShell1.ps1:98 char:1
+ $JournalAmount = [double] $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Amount'].Va ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToDoubleOrSingle

---

## Here is my code:

```
Get-Content "config.txt" | foreach-object -begin {$h=@{}} -process { $k = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($k[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($k[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True)) { $h.Add($k[0], $k[1]) } }

$FileBrowserInitialDir = $h.FileBrowserInitialDir
$Header = 'Terminal','Company','Journal Account Code','Project','Task','Line of Business','Date','Journal Amount','Report Entry Vendor Description'

$TIDataFilePath = $h.TIDataFilePath
$TIDataFileBaseName = $h.TIDataFileBaseName

$TIScreenID = $h.TIScreenID
$TIControlFile = $h.TIControlFile
$TIErrLog = $h.TIErrLog

$ResultsFilePath = $h.ResultsFilePath
$ResultsFileBaseName = $h.ResultsFileBaseName

$dt = Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyyHHmmss"
$TIDataFile = "$($TIDataFileBaseName)$($dt).txt"
$ResultsFile = "$($ResultsFileBaseName)$($dt).txt"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = $FileBrowserInitialDir
    Filter = 'CSV (*.csv)|*.csv'
    Title = "Select Expense csv file"
}
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

if($FileBrowser.FileName -eq ""){
    exit
}


 $EXPENSECSV = Import-CSV $FileBrowser.FileName -Header $Header
 New-Item -path $TIDataFilePath -name $TIDataFile -type "file"
 $EXPENSECSV |foreach-object{    

$Terminal =  $_.PSObject.Properties['Terminal'].Value
$Terminal = $Terminal.Insert(0,'0')

$CompanyTemp =  $_.PSObject.Properties['Company'].Value
$CompanyTemp = $CompanyTemp.Insert(0,'0')
#$Company= [String]::Concat($_.Terminal,$CompanyTemp) 
$Company= [String]::Concat($Terminal,$CompanyTemp) 
$LineofB =  $_.PSObject.Properties['Line of Business'].Value
#$JournalAmount = [double] $_.PSObject.Properties["Journal Amount"].Value
 $LineofB = $LineofB.Insert(0,'0')

 $Account = $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Account Code'].Value
$Sub = $LineofB

$TranDateStr =  $_.PSObject.Properties['Date'].Value
$JournalAmount = [double] $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Amount'].Value
$Description =  $_.PSObject.Properties['Report Entry Vendor Description'].Value

    $row = ""
    $row +=  "`"Level1`","
    $row +=  "`"$($Company)`","
    $row +=  "`"$($Account)`","
    $row +=  "`"$($Sub)`","
    $row +=  "`"$($TranDateStr)`","


    # Convert Concur Amount to Credit/Debit Amount
    # Postive Amount  --> Debit Amount
    # Negative Amount --> Credit Amount
    if($JournalAmount -lt 0){
        $JournalAmount*= -1
        $row += "`"$($JournalAmount)`","   #Credit Amount
        $row += "`"`","             #Debit Amount
    }
    else {
        $row += "`"`","             #Credit Amount
        $row += "`"$($JournalAmount)`","   #Debit Amount
    }

    $row += "`"$($Description)`""

   Add-Content -Path "$($TIDataFilePath)$($TIDataFile)" -Value $row
 }

 #Results
 New-Item -path $ResultsFilePath -name $ResultsFile -type "file"

 $ResultsStr =   "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`n"
$ResultsStr +=  "                             Concur to Dynamics SL                                   `n"
$ResultsStr +=  "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`n"
$ResultsStr +=  "Copy and paste the following into the Transaction Import screen.`n"
$ResultsStr += "Line 1: Data File Name`n"
$ResultsStr += "Line 2: Screen ID`n"
$ResultsStr += "Line 3: Control File Name`n"
$ResultsStr += "Line 4: Output Log File`n`n`n"
$ResultsStr += "$($TIDataFilePath)$($TIDataFile)`n"
$ResultsStr += "$($TIScreenID)`n"
$ResultsStr += "$($TIControlFile)`n"
$ResultsStr += "$($TIErrLog)"


 Add-Content -path "$($ResultsFilePath)$($ResultsFile)" -value $ResultsStr

Start-Process "$($ResultsFilePath)$($ResultsFile)"
```

Comment: Does your CSV file already have a header on the first line? When you specify `-Header $Header` with `Import-Csv`, it interprets all the lines as data (including the first line), which would explain you getting the value "Journal Amount" in the "Journal Amount" column :)

Comment: Have you tried writing the value that's not getting converted out to the console?  Add a line like `Write-Host $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Amount'].Value` before the line where the error is occuring, that might help you to understand why that value can't be converted to a Double

Comment: @Matias R. Jessen  ...Yes my csv file already has a header on the first line. What do I use instead of -Header $Header?

Answer (score 14):

To answer the question as asked:

- **Casting a string to `[double]`** - as you've attempted yourself - ***does* work**, but only if the string is recognized as a (floating-point) number.

  - **Caveat**: Since **PowerShell's casts are culture-*invariant*, only `.` is recognized as the decimal mark**, and `,` is always interpreted as the thousands-grouping separator.
  - To **parse culture-*sensitively***, use **`[double]::Parse($string)`** to parse based on the rules of the *current* culture (as reflected in `$PSCulture`); pass a `[cultureinfo]` instance as the second argument to parse based on the rules of a *given* culture (e.g., to parse based on the rules of the French culture, use `[double]::Parse($string, [cultureinfo] 'fr-FR')`)
- **If the string value is *not* recognized**, you can use one of the following approaches to handle that case:

  - **Use [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally)** to handle the error; e.g., to quietly default to `0`:

    - `[double] $double = try { $string } catch { 0 }`
  - **Use `-as`**, the [conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators), which either returns an instance of the specified type or, if the conversion fails, `$null`:

    - `$double = $string -as [double]; if ($null -eq $double) { ... }`

---

As for **what you tried**:

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, the likely cause of your problem is that your CSV file does a have a header row itself, yet you also supplied headers via the `-Header` parameter.

This results in the CSV file's header line to be misread *as the first data row*, as a result of which the first object returned by `Import-Csv` then contains the *column (header) names* as property values - which then causes the `[double]` cast to fail, given that you're effectively executing the following:
`[double] 'Journal Amount'`

Therefore:

- Omit the `-Header` parameter in your `Import-Csv` call.
- As an optimization, simplify the property-value retrieval by using normal dot notation; simply use *quoting* to specify property name `Journal Amount`, because it contains a space:

```
Import-CSV $FileBrowser.FileName | # !! No -Header argument
  ForEach-Object {
    # Simpler and more efficient than:
    #   $JournalAmount = [double] $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Amount'].Value
    $JournalAmount = [double] $_.'Journal Amount'
  }
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

```
$JournalAmount = $JournalAmount -as [double]
$JournalAmount = $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Amount'].Value
```

Comment: I don't think this fixed the issue, it just hides the error. With `$JournalAmount` having no preexisting value / not being previously defined, your first statement is an effective no-op. The second statement completely negates any effects of the first statement, and simply stores a _string_ value in `$JournalAmount`. You were probably thinking of _type-constraining_ a variable, by placing the "cast" to the _left_ of the variable name: `[double] $JournalAmount = $_.PSObject.Properties['Journal Amount'].Value`; however, that wouldn't help in your case.